# PHP form handling

Tags: php

I began following a tutorial about PHP. Reached the form handling. But here it is: when I do what they say and press Submit, it gives me to save the .php file instead of executing it? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an [HTTP server](http://httpd.apache.org) that [supports PHP and is configured to use it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php). PHP (in the context on the WWW) is a server side technology.

Answer (score 1):

You may not actually be running a web server, and instead may be simply loading local files in your web browser.  Install an easy setup web server and PHP setup package. On Windows, [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is recommended. On MacOS, the equivalent is [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

Rather than opening files from your local drive, you then access them as (for example):

```
http://localhost/your_php_file.php
```

Comment: You mean that it`s impossible to do it on local level like just testing some htmls? I have to do it from the lampp server?

Comment: It is possible, you just have to install and configure Apache web server and PHP.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov You can run a server on your local machine. That is how web development is usually done.

Comment: @Ilian Zapryanov — You can't use a server side technology without a server. You don't have to install Linux, there are HTTP servers for just about every platform, and PHP runs on quite a lot of them. (It is a good idea to use a development platform that matches your deployment environment as closely as possible though, VirtualBox is helpful for this).

Answer (score 0):

It is a misconfiguration of the server. Perhaps the recommendations [here](http://www.wrensoft.com/forum/showthread.php?t=1031) could help. Either PHP isn't installed or Apache was not configured.

Comment: Could you explain to OP how to solve the issue?

Comment: it`s done from a local drive not on server level.

Comment: Check if PHP is installed and Apache is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Apache server and required PHP installation.

If you are on windows. Go to this link [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and select Downloads and download the latest version of Wamp.

For Mac OS you can use [Mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

Download and install it in your machine.

If you are on Linux - Ubuntu you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

After installation place your php code in configured folder where the php is set to run  and then go to browser and take the url : `http://localhost/yourphp.file`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Note that Mac OS/X ships with Apache httpd and PHP built-in.  You don't need to install an extra package, you just have to configure what's already there.

Comment: @Sabari , I am linux user/admin, I got that working on lampp sending all files to /opt/lampp/htdocs, but I was thinkig that this would work normally by just parsing with browser...